# Retrieve Urls from SQL Database and display the images in a repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

So basically Its a image uploader and Image viewer project.

I am able to upload the image to a local folder and just save the image url in database which looks like [image: Image database]

Now next the user should be able to view the images based on the palbum and pcat selected. palbum = album names. pcat = Public,Private etc(ignore the first pcat being animal).

**Now on Page 1 my code will be:**

```
protected void btn_view_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Response.Redirect("viewimage.aspx?album='"+DropDownList_album.SelectedValue+"'&cat='"+DropDownList_category.SelectedValue+"'");
    }
```

**On Page 2 I have applied a repeater and want to display only those pictures based on the queries only.**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string album = Request.QueryString["album"];
        string cat = Request.QueryString["cat"];


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(" *hiding this* ");
        con.Open();

        string cmd = "select * from Pics where palbum='" + Request.QueryString["album"].ToString() + "' and pcat='" + Request.QueryString["cat"].ToString() +"'";     // have tried replacing select purl with select * but same problem.

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        adp.Fill(dt);

        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind(); 
    }
```

**But everytime i try this with different syntax and what not I either get a blank screen with no images in the repeater or this error:**

[image]

Comment: Could you debug and post the value of `cmd`?

Comment: Its giving me "Flowers"

Comment: Not the result, the sql command.

Comment: select * from Pics where palbum="Flowers" and pcat="Public"

Comment: The error is pointing to a SQL problem

Comment: Replace `"` by a single quote `'`

Comment: select * from Pics where palbum='Flowers' and pcat='Public'

Comment: my command is string cmd = "select * from Pics where palbum='" + Request.QueryString["album"].ToString() + "' and pcat='" + Request.QueryString["cat"].ToString() +"'";

Comment: how can i change the quotes here?

Comment: @Sam, set a debug break-point after `string cmd = select ....` and print it real value.

Comment: ok ill do it and report back!

Comment: You got a problem with the invalid SQL and a couple of other problems there: 1) You should close the connection. 2) Your code is subject to SQL Injection via URL manipulating. You should use parametrized queries

Comment: @bradbury9 yes i have closed the connection later and i know about parameterized queries but this is just a fun project in a vm so its ok :P

Answer (score 1):

Depending on SQL Server parameters, double quotes are no accepted, if I recall correctly is `quote_identifier` parameter.

You have a hidden problem that could be troublesome called SQL Injection. Yous should get rid of both problems altogether using parametrized queries:

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(" *hiding this* ");
        con.Open();

```
    string cmd = "select * from Pics where palbum= @album and pcat=@cat";     


    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);

    adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@album", Request.QueryString["album"]);
    adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", Request.QueryString["cat"]);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    adp.Fill(dt);


    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i forgot to put ItemTemplate tag inside the Repeater therefore i wasn't getting the output. sorry guys